# Как уменьшить окно Powershell и изменить фон?

Tags: powershell

Раньше в виндовом проводнике при нажатиии "Shift+прав.кнопка мышки" в контекстном меню можно было выбрать комадную строку.
Теперь вместо этого пункта, почему-то, красуется "Открыть окно Powershel здесь", котороее открывается на 2/3 экрана (и это на 17дюймовом то ноуте...) и имеет синий фон, на котором некоторые строчки сливаются с ним и их не видно.
Вопрос: что сделать, чтобы при старте, окно Powershel было маленьким и фон был черным?
Ну или как вместо powershel, при нажатиии "Shift+прав.кнопка мышки" в контекстном меню проводника, вернуть командную строку?

Comment: откройте PS. в настройках профиля смените размер шрифта, размер окна, цвет фона, цвет текста. сохраните и вауля

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Откройте окно powershell, системном меню (левый верхний угол), выберите пункт "Свойства", чтобы изменить только для данного окна или "Умолчания", чтобы изменить для всех консольных окон.

Стоит заметить, что изменения будут внесены в том случае, если нет ярлыка. В противном случае, данные настройки нужно менять в ярлыке (или при сохранении, указать, что изменения внести в ярлык).